# Printing out a value from a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I am new to programming.

I'm trying to print out the value of a key within a nested dictionary.

```py
ROOM = ""
ROOM_DESC = ""
ROOM_THIS = ""
ROOM_THAT = ""
ROOM_EXM = ""

randdict = {
  "a1": {
    ROOM: "room name",
    ROOM_DESC: "room desc",
    ROOM_THIS: "room this",
    ROOM_THAT: "room that",
    ROOM_EXM: "room exm",
  }
}

print(randdict["a1"][ROOM] + "\n" + randdict["a1"][ROOM_DESC] + "\n" + randdict["a1"][ROOM_THIS])
```

The result I was expecting was:

```
room name
room desc
room this
```

Instead what I got was:

```
room exm
room exm
room exm
```

Not quite sure what went wrong there, an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: All the keys (i.e. ROOM, ROOM_DESC, etc.) are equal, namely "".  Need to make them different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different values of ROOM, ROOM_DESC, ROOM_THIS, ROOM_THAT and ROOM_EXM. Dictionaries must have unique keys.

```
ROOM = "1"
ROOM_DESC = "2"
ROOM_THIS = "3"
ROOM_THAT = "4"
ROOM_EXM = "5"

randdict = {
  "a1": {
    ROOM: "room name",
    ROOM_DESC: "room desc",
    ROOM_THIS: "room this",
    ROOM_THAT: "room that",
    ROOM_EXM: "room exm",
  }
}

print(randdict["a1"][ROOM] + "\n" + randdict["a1"][ROOM_DESC] + "\n" + randdict["a1"][ROOM_THIS])
```

Answer (score 1):

change your keys to the following.

```
randdict = {
  "a1": {
    'ROOM' : "room name",
    'ROOM_DESC' : "room desc",
    'ROOM_THIS': "room this",
    'ROOM_THAT': "room that",
    'ROOM_EXM': "room exm",
  }
}


    print(f"{randdict['a1']['ROOM']} \n{randdict['a1']['ROOM_DESC']} \n{randdict['a1']['ROOM_THIS']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

ROOM, ROOM_DESC, ROOM_THIS, ROOM_THAT and ROOM_EXM are all "". this causes the dictionary to be overwritten, and because the last entry was room exm that is what gets printed (because it wasn't overwritten). If you switch the room variables to be unique it should work

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that all your variables ROOM_* are the same empty string. So your dictionary is being created only with the last key/value ROOM_EXM: "room exm".

You can check that by printing your dictionary.

You should assign some string to your variables ROOM_*. Even something like:

```
ROOM = "ROOM"
ROOM_DESC = "ROOM_DESC"
ROOM_THIS = "ROOM_THIS"
ROOM_THAT = "ROOM_THAT"
ROOM_EXM = "ROOM_EXM"
```